# Option Values with problematic Values

Tags: custom-fields

I'm getting this status message:

> The Following Option Values contain value fields that do not match the Data Type of the Option Group

It references an Option Group and a option value of "No". The actual option value is 0 (zero) and the label is "No". The table looks ok. The field is defined as an int(11) and all of the records have values of 0, 1, 2, or Null. This option group is shared by another custom field, but no warning about that one. I haven't had any issues entering or displaying data.

Comment: I've also seen this with 4.7 where Civi is complaining about what is perfectly valid data.  See also https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/16158/system-status-notice-about-option-value-0-in-number-field?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

I believe we solved this. The option group in question is a multiple choice integer (radio buttons) with values 0, 1, and 2 representing "No", "Yes",and "Retest". Nulls are allowed. All values in the table matched. Other than the warning, we never experienced any issues.

We noticed that standard Yes/No option groups used 0 and 1 values, but other multiple choice integer option groups used non-zero positive  integers. We reset all of our "No" records to value 3 and changed the Option Group to match. The warning immediately stopped.

Comment: this might beg the question of how the option values got set up that way in the first place?

Comment: We set those values when we added a custom field for a radio selection. The field represents the successful completion of a test where the possibilities are Untested (Null), No (was 0, now 3), Yes (1), Retest (2).  When we looked at some of the standard option groups, such as Skill Level, we noticed they don't include zero. Another thing we noticed, our option group is an integer (int11), but others are alphanumeric.

Answer (score 1):

I would check to just make sure that there are no option values that aren't an Integer. That check was put in due to issues where option values were being added to option groups that were used in some parts of the system where they were expected to be an Integer but there was not data check on the option value adding / edit screens

Regards

Seamus

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand why setting '0' as an option value will generate this warning (I'm seeing this myself now on a new option group that I've just set up)?